# How use custom features in Keras for text classification

Tags: python, keras, classification, data-analysis, text-classification

I'm working for a text classificator in Python using Keras. For now I tried so make model only with the words of my dataset, using **bag of words**. Now I would use in my classifier other custom features (like polarity) but I don't know how to add there in my code. My dataset is like:

```
 Text                    | Polarity | Number of words | Classification 

 Hello my name is John   |    0,05  |        5        |        0
 How old are you?        |    0,00  |        4        |        1
 I'm very hungry         |   -0,05  |        4        |        0
```

The middle two colums are my custom features that i want add to my classifier but I don't know how.

```
train_x = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(allWordIndices, mode='binary')
train_x2 = train_x

train_x = train_x[1000:]
test_x = train_x2[:1000]
train_y = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_y, 2)
train_y2 = train_y
train_y = train_y[1000:]
test_y = train_y2[:1000]


from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_shape=(max_words,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.45)) 
model.add(Dense(100, activation='softplus'))
model.add(Dropout(0.45))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='RMSProp',metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_x,train_y,batch_size=32,epochs=10,verbose=1,validation_split=0.1,shuffle=True)

score = model.evaluate(test_x,test_y, batch_size=128)
```

In this example i use only bag of words feature of the content f first column and i want add other 2 column like features (polarity, number of words). Someone has an idea how add these? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Bag of words you can just concatenate your numerical features on top of your BoW vector. Therefore you can just use numpy, or even easier pandas. Then you have a vector with the dimension max_words + custom_numerical_features.

Anyway I did somthing similar and worked a lot with several approaches like BoW and embeddings.

It is a good idea to sperate text features and numerical features in your network. To do so you can use multiple input models. I just wrote a blog about it you can take a look [here](http://digital-thinking.de/deep-learning-combining-numerical-and-text-features-in-deep-neural-networks/). There are embeddings used, but in general it works also for BoW.